# How to test a callback in a callback using sinon?

Tags: javascript, node.js, unit-testing, callback, sinon

I am trying to get my codes to 100% coverage.

Right now, what i am missing is this line:

`(err, result) => this.processDBResult(err, result, id, req, res, CLASS_NAME, METHOD_NAME, stopwatch)`

and

```
 (accounttype) => globUtil.getConfig(accounttype, constant.BOOK,
            source => this.generateData(req, res, stopwatch, className, methodName, result, source))
```

How do i proceed in doing that?

I try stuff like :

```
getIdSpy.callsFake(() => {
    sinon.assert.callCount(processDBResultSpy, 4);      
});
```

But it will always return success and i know that my `processDBResultSpy` is not called 4 times, only once.

Codes:

```
exports.getBookInfo = (req, res) => {

    let stopwatch = globUtil.startStopWatch();

    const METHOD_NAME = "getBookInfo";

    const id = req.params.id;
    const params = [id];

    if (globUtil.isId(id)) {
        bookDao.getBookById(params,
            (err, result) => this.processDBResult(err, result, id, req, res, CLASS_NAME, METHOD_NAME, stopwatch));

    } else {
        bookDao.getBookBySelfId(params,
            (err, result) => this.processDBResult(err, result, id, req, res, CLASS_NAME, METHOD_NAME, stopwatch));
    }
};

 exports.processDBResult = (err, result, id, req, res, className, methodName, stopwatch) => {

    if (err) {
        log.error(err);

        this.generateErrorResponse(req, res, 500, err, stopwatch, className, methodName);

        return;
    }

    if (result.length == 0) {
        log.info("No results");
        this.generateErrorResponse(req, res, 404, format(message.NOT_FOUND, id), stopwatch, className, methodName)

        return;
    }

    globUtil.getAccountType(id,
        (accounttype) => globUtil.getConfig(accounttype, constant.BOOK,
            source => this.generateData(req, res, stopwatch, className, methodName, result, source)));
}
```

Test case:

```
it('1. getBookInfo - called with id', (done) => {
        let getIdSpy = sinon.stub(bookDao, "getBookById");
        let getSelfIdSpy = sinon.stub(bookDao, "getBookBySelfId");
        let processDBResultSpy = sinon.stub(controller, "processDBResult");

        let request = httpMocks.createRequest({
            method: 'GET',
            url: constant.MODULE_URL,
            params: {
                id: 'BOOKID'
            }
        });

        let response = httpMocks.createResponse();
        controller.getHdbInfo(request, response);

        sinon.assert.callCount(getIdSpy, 1);
        sinon.assert.callCount(getSelfIdSpy, 0);

        //how do i proceed form here

        done();
    });
```

Comment: well if you are stubbing a method, then how can you test that methods calls the callback? I suggest to remove the stubs and use spy to check if the callbacks are called with right args.

Comment: @AvishekSaha using spy makes my app run the access db which I do not want it to. So what I do i yields my stub calls.

Answer (score 0):

Finally got answer to this. What I do is that I yields my methods.

```
it('1. getBookInfo - called with id', (done) => {
        let getIdSpy = sinon.stub(bookDao, "getBookById").yields(null, []);
        let getSelfIdSpy = sinon.stub(bookDao, "getBookBySelfId");
        let processDBResultSpy = sinon.stub(controller, "processDBResult");

        let request = httpMocks.createRequest({
            method: 'GET',
            url: constant.MODULE_URL,
            params: {
                id: 'BOOKID'
            }
        });

        let response = httpMocks.createResponse();
        controller.getHdbInfo(request, response);

        sinon.assert.callCount(getIdSpy, 1);
        sinon.assert.callCount(getSelfIdSpy, 0);

        //how do i proceed form here
        sinon.assert.callCount(processDBResultSpy, 1);

        done();
    });
```